# Replacing multiple substrings with respective replacements

Tags: haskell, replace

I have a `String` that contains several tags in the form `${...}` (where `...` can be any string that doesn't contain a `}` character), for example `foo ${bar} baz ${qux}`.

I would like to replace these tags, but to do that I need a function in the form:

```
replace :: [String] -> [String] -> String -> String
--           tags    replacements  target    result
replace ["${bar}", "${qux}"] ["abc", "def"] "foo ${bar} baz ${qux}" == "foo abc baz def"
```

(This is similar to PHP's [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function when given arrays as arguments.)

I couldn't find such a replace function in any package. Is there such a function, and if there isn't how would I write it (pointing in the right direction is enough; I'm learning Haskell)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a one-liner:

```
Prelude Data.Text> Prelude.foldr (uncurry Data.Text.replace) "foo ${bar} baz ${qux}" $ Prelude.zip ["${bar}", "${qux}"] ["abc", "def"]
"foo abc baz def"
```

In other words:

```
replace as bs x = Prelude.foldr (uncurry Data.Text.replace) x $  Prelude.zip as bs
```